# Trouble with writing and reading using fstream (windows forms, C++/CLI)

Tags: c++, winforms, file, c++-cli, fstream

I'm creating a small program to take in (possibly) multiplexed serial data from a serial port but having trouble with this function involving reading and writing to my output file.
Everything compiles fine using windows forms.

**Here's what's supposed to happen: [code snippets below]**

at the beginning of the program, a file is created and this inserted:

```
DC1
DC2
DC3
DC4
JUNK:
```

~blah blah blah, COMport stuff happens and we get a string containing one piece of data~

And we come to the "WriteToFile" function which has a piece of data passed to it. (say 0.95)
"NumberCheck" filters the data of all non-numeric(but incl '.') parts (incase of junk).
Each line of the file is read, its length added to count and checked for which "zone" the data will go into. If it's the right line, stop line-reading as the marker should point to the position in the file at the end of that line. (fs is a failsafe counter incase something odd happens). Then i find the length of the file from that position to the end, resize temp to suit, fill temp with what's after the marker (incl that position), and output my data and temp at the marker... theoretically inserting my data into the correct place.

**The problem I'm having** is that after the first run through of "WriteToFile", fileline comes up with nothing so the marker never finds its' place.
Also, even after flushing the text file shows no signs of changes (is it the right way to implement the stream?)

**Here's the relevant code:**
Opening the file:

```
//opening file with the name in the textbox
string myfilename = txtboxCONT;
myfilename.append(".txt");
myfilename="test.txt"; //temporary name, DELETE BEFORE PUBLISH <<.
fstream myfile(myfilename,ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
if (!myfile.is_open())          
    throw;

//initial file set-up
int i;
for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
    myfile << "DC" << i << "\n";
myfile << "JUNK:";
myfile.flush();
```

And my writing function:

```
void WriteToFile(fstream &myfile, string& data, int zone)
{
    data = NumberCheck(data); //filters out non-numeric data, returns "null" if nothing left.
    if (data=="null")       //if the filter leaves no valid output, no need to write.
        return;

    myfile.seekg(0);     //set initial position at the start?
    string fileline, srch, out;
    stringstream ss; //for int to string conversion
    ss << zone;
    srch="DC";
    srch.append(ss.str());
    int fs=1, marker=0;
    while(fs<=4)        //test each line if it beins with DC(zone)
    {
        getline(myfile, fileline);
        marker = marker + fileline.length() + 1;
        if (srch==fileline.substr(0,3))
            break;
        fs++;
    }

    if (fs!=5)
    {
        //can't avoid overwriting so... this is gon' suck...
        string temp;
        myfile.seekg(0,ios::end);
        int length = myfile.tellg();
        length = length - marker;
        temp.resize(length);
        myfile.seekg(marker);
        myfile.read(&temp[0],temp.size());
        myfile.seekp(marker);
        myfile << ',' << data << temp;
    }
    else
    {
        myfile.seekp(0,ios::end);
        myfile << ',' << data;
    }
    myfile.flush();
    data.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `string::find`, to find out the DC1, DC2, DC3 ?

Have a look at the [string library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream).

By the way, I can't post a comment on your question.

You should do something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std;

void WriteToFile(fstream &myfile, string& data, int zone)
{

    string fileline, srch;
    stringstream ss; //for int to string conversion
    ss << zone;
    srch="DC";
    srch.append(ss.str());

    int offset; 
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile, fileline);
        if ((offset = fileline.find(srch, 0)) != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "My search " << srch << endl;
        }
    }

    myfile.clear();
    myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    // Write here

}


int main()
{
    string myfilename = "test";
    myfilename.append(".txt");
    myfilename="test.txt"; //temporary name, DELETE BEFORE PUBLISH <<.
    fstream myfile(myfilename,ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
    if (!myfile.is_open())          
    throw;

    //initial file set-up
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++)  myfile << "DC" << i << "\n";
    myfile << "JUNK:";
    myfile.flush();


    string write = "blalblablab";
    WriteToFile(myfile, write, 1);
    WriteToFile(myfile, write, 2);
    WriteToFile(myfile, write, 3);

    WriteToFile(myfile, write, 4);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have to construct the string that I'm searching for. If i used 'string::find' with a varying third digit, would it make anything simpler?

Comment: You already construct your string to search correctly. I edited the answer.

Comment: If it helps, i don't see why not :)